# Unepic: Where i can find the first healing tome?

Tags: unepic

I bought one Healing tome but it says I need level 1 of healing to copy it in my spellbook.

Where i find the first tome to learn the healing spell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you need level 1 in the Healing *skill*. Next time you level up, put a point there.

The same goes for other schools of magic: in order to learn spells you first need to assigned points to the corresponding magic skill.

If you don't have the skill yet, you learn it by completing the quest "Search of the Mandragora" in the gardens; this is the third major area you visit and healing is the third school of magic.